# Is a Web Crawler more suitable?

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

**TL;DR Version :**
I have only heard about web crawlers in intelluctual conversations Im not part of. All I want to know that can they follow a specific path like:

```
first page (has lot of links) -->go to links specified-->go to
 links(specified, yes again)-->go to certain link-->reach final page
 and download source.
```

I have googled a bit and came across [Scrappy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html). But I am not sure if I fully understand web crawlers to begin with and if scrappy can help me follow the specific path I want.

**Long Version**

I wanted to extract some text of a group of static web pages. These web pages are very simple with just basic `HTML`. I used `python` and the `urllib` to access the `URL`,extract the text and work with it. Pretty soon I realized that I will have to basically visit all these pages and copy paste the `URL` into my program, which is tiresome. I wanted to know if this is more suitable for a web crawler. I want to access [this](http://rebase.neb.com/cgi-bin/pacbiolist)
page. Then select only a few `organisms` (I have a list of those). On Clicking on of them you can see [this](http://rebase.neb.com/cgi-bin/pacbioget?6503) page. If you look under the table - `MTases active in the genome` there are `Enzymes` which are `hyperlinks`. Clinking on those lead to [this](http://rebase.neb.com/rebase/enz/M1.Apa12260I.html) page. On the right hand side there is link named `Sequence Data`. Once clicked it leads to the page which has a small table on the lower right with yellow headers. under it it has an entry `DNA (FASTA STYLE`. Clicking on view will lead to the page im interested in and want to download the page source from.

Comment: Yes you can. If you look at `Scrapy`'s documentation more closely , they have ways to help you follow the path you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are definitely on the right track for looking at a web crawler to help you do this.  You can also look at [Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/) which I know can let you follow links on a page without storing that page if is is just a listing page to you.  That crawler lets you filter out pages after their links have been extracted to be followed.  Ultimately, you can configure the right filters so that only the pages matching the pattern you want get downloaded for you to process (whether it is based on crawl depth, URL pattern, content pattern, etc).